# Algebra to reconcile 2 alternative forms of negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am given that negative binomial, "failure version" follows
Where
X: Trials
Y: Failures
r: successes

${y+r-1  \choose r-1}p^r(1-p)^y$

However, I am ALSO told that I can use the expression

${y+r-1  \choose y}p^r(1-p)^y$

How is this algebraically possible, that is, how is $r-1=y$?

Comment: For any $m,n\in\Bbb{N}$, the binomial coefficient admits a symmetry: $C(m+n,n)=C(m+n,m)$

Comment: I apologize but I do not understand your answer. Is there an algebraic demonstration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment,
$$C(m+n,n)=\frac{(m+n)!}{n!(m+n-n)!}=\frac{(m+n)!}{n!m!}$$
and
$$C(m+n,m)=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!(m+n-m)!}=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$$
QED.